# Upload documents from Amazon s3 to CloudSearch using AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudsearch

How to upload document from Amazon S3 to Cloud Search using AWS Java SDK and make it indexable as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I does not found any direct way within the SDK to index document from S3 to Cloud Search. So i use like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to proceed about making the documents in input stream searchable and indexable?